# Complex schema validation issues

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I'm close to achieving the goal of unit testing views in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project.  I have the XML output as a string, and want to validate against the standard VoiceXML 2.1 schema.  I downloaded said schema from w3.org, but two issues:

1. Validation takes several minutes
2. I'm getting an error "reference to undeclared model group 'http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml:audio'".

I suspect the reason is that the main schema refers to several included schemas that are being retrieved (or not) over the web.  I'm seeing the following in the schema file:

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="vxml-datatypes.xsd"/>    
<xsd:include schemaLocation="vxml-attribs.xsd"/>    
<xsd:include schemaLocation="vxml-grammar-extension.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="vxml-synthesis-extension.xsd"/>

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
            schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

I'm loading the schema in my unit test as follows:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml", "../../../IVRUnitTests/VoiceXML21Schema.xsd");
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

I've downloaded the included schemas referenced in the main one.  Can I also add them to my XmlReaderSettings.Schemas collection?  If so, will the validation not go looking over the web for them?  Any other advice for validating against such a complex schema?

P.S.  Where's the best place to put the schema in the unit test project so it will automatically be copied/referenced where I need it?  The '../../' thing is kludgey.

Comment: It shouldn't be going to the Internet by default. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) or something like it to see if there's any traffic. Many of the URLs you're seeing do not refer to locations on the Internet. They're just namespaces in URL format.

Comment: Additionally, you need to add all of those schemas to the schemaset.

Comment: I ended up adding all the schemas - it's still way too slow to be usable.  I think I'll have to give up unless VS 2010 can somehow speed the process up.